# Automatic Windows Authentication without login dialog using Identity Server 4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

We have a setup where Identity Server 4 (IS4), running in IIS using .NET Core 3.1, will authenticate users via Windows AD or credentials stored in a database.  The problem I'm trying to resolve is when we have an internal web site, currently built using ReactJS, that authenticates against IS4, a dialog popups up asking for the user to enter their credentials.  What we want is for the user to be automatically logged into IS4 via their Windows domain account with no prompt for the user to enter their credentials.

Below is the setup
**IIS**

- SSL enabled
- Authentication:  Anonymous and Windows Authentication Enabled.

**IS4**

- Web Host definition (Program.cs)
  `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseSerilog().UseStartup<Startup>();`
- Windows Authentication Configuration (Startup.cs)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
    {
        ...
        services.Configure<IISOptions>(iis =>
        {
            iis.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
            iis.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        ...
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthorization();
    }
```

**ReactJS**

- Nothing special configured here.
- Running via npm start from the command line, not using IIS.

I think that is all of the related code and configuration.  We have logic that is setup to detect if the client is configured for automatic Windows authentication so that they don't get redirected to the IS4 Account login page.

Answer (score 0):

Is the IIS a part of the AD domain?

Do you have

```
options.ListenerSettings.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate | AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM;
```

enabled? From Identity Server doc: https://docs.identityserver.io/en/aspnetcore1/topics/windows.html

I don't believe I had to enable anything else last time I did it.

Comment: thanks for the pointers.  We're using Kestrel for the web hosting so setting the Listeners isn't an option.  Something I did notice is that the login popup only appears to happen in Chrome.  Firefox and IE behave as expected and automatically login the user.  So this may not be an IS4 issue and actually a Chrome issue.?.?

Comment: Can't you add the listeners to the IS setup? So when you send the customers to the IS, it checks for NTLM and redirects automatically if the auth i present? Otherwise show the login screen? Maybe I misunderstood your question :-)